# How to get elements in order that are placed via translate3d

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, frontend

I am building a Chrome extension that interacts with Youtube comments visible on the screen in my Youtube backend. I want the extension to **traverse the list of comments** and highlight them one by one like so:

[image]

I get the comments on the screen in the following way:

```
return document.querySelectorAll(".ytcp-comment-thread .style-scope.ytcp-comments-section #comment")[currentIndex]
```

and then maintain `currentIndex` to know at what element I am currently at.

This works for the first couple of comments but then it starts highlighting the wrong comment. After inspecting the page, I noticed that the order of the comment `div`s doesn't exactly represent the order of comments on the screen. Instead, they seem to be placed by an attribute called `translate3d`:

[image]

How can I accurately traverse all of these comments on the screen?

**Edit**: Here is an example of how Youtube puts the last comments of the page (loaded lazily) at the top of the HTML elements:

[image]

And as code:

```
<div class="ytcp-comment-thread style-scope ytcp-comments-section" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 11596px, 0px);">

<div class="ytcp-comment-thread style-scope ytcp-comments-section" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 11800px, 0px);">

<div class="ytcp-comment-thread style-scope ytcp-comments-section" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 12004px, 0px);">

<div class="style-scope ytcp-comments-section" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 12208px, 0px);">

<div class="ytcp-comment-thread style-scope ytcp-comments-section" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 980px, 0px);">

<div class="ytcp-comment-thread style-scope ytcp-comments-section" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 1184px, 0px);">
```

Comment: Could you put a (short) example of the HTML you are receiving, say just half a dozen comments but with some 'in the wrong order' - it might help think through the problem.

Comment: @AHaworth I think the HTML is too big to paste it here but I added a screenshot that shows the problem.

Comment: Could you paste say the first 7 - I can see what it is from the image but don't feel like typing it in :)

Comment: @AHaworth I added some code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the given code (which is just part of a longer list and hence there are gaps in the layout) we can go through sorting the elements in terms of their y translations.

The sorted array has entries of the form [i, y] where i is the index within the collection of children of #items and y is the px value of the translation.

To illustrate that the sorting has produced the order in which the comments are to be highlighted a setTimeout function highlights them in turn. This is not likely to be what you want to do - it is here just as a simple demo:

```js
const items = document.querySelector('#items').children;
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  arr.push([i, Number(items[i].style.transform.split('translate3d(0px, ')[1].split('px')[0])]);
}
let sortedArr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[1] - b[1];
});
let next = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  if (next > 0) {
    items[sortedArr[next - 1][0]].classList.remove('hilite');
  }
  items[sortedArr[next][0]].classList.add('hilite');
  if (next < (arr.length - 1)) next++;
}, 5000);
```

```css
.hilite {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="items">
  <div class="ytcp-comment-thread style-scope ytcp-comments-section" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 11596px, 0px);">content 11596</div>

  <div class="ytcp-comment-thread style-scope ytcp-comments-section" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 11800px, 0px);">content 11800</div>

  <div class="ytcp-comment-thread style-scope ytcp-comments-section" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 12004px, 0px);">content 12004</div>

  <div class="style-scope ytcp-comments-section" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 12208px, 0px);">content 12208</div>

  <div class="ytcp-comment-thread style-scope ytcp-comments-section" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 980px, 0px);">content 980</div>

  <div class="ytcp-comment-thread style-scope ytcp-comments-section" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 1184px, 0px);">content 1184</div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to scroll down (quite a way) to see the highlighting happening.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')`

Comment: It seems to work if I start at `i = 1` instead of 0 for the loop. I'm still trying to figure out how to use the return value to get the correct HTML element.

Comment: Are you seeing that error when you run the snippet above or is it when running your own code?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest because the code preview has huge gaps between the elements and the window is small, so I can't really see what's happening. But it seems to work!

Comment: Unfortunately, it still stops working after a few comments. I'm probably missing some weird quirk in the HMTL structure.

Comment: You could try taking a copy of the snippet and inserting all the divs you have and see what happens as a test. It's possibly that you've got some other types of styling in some of them.

Comment: I've copied your snippet into my code and it works for the first couple of comments, but then it stops working. I must be missing something in this weird HTML structure but thank you for your help!

Comment: I take that back, it's actually working! The reason why it didn't work was that I added my own additional selector which messed things up.

Any idea how I could take lazy loading into account so it doesn't mix up the list/index?

Comment: Hmm, lazy loading would throw a spanner in the works I guess since we are relying on everything being available at once - and what would it mean if the element with lowest y translation actually was at the bottom of the list? I don't think I can work out what to do on that one.

Comment: No problem, thank you for all your help!

Comment: One more question: Let's say I listen for lazy load events and regenerate the list (sorted by translate3d). How can I get the position of the currently highlighted element (the one with the `hilite` attribute) in that new list? This way I could continue after lazy loads.

Comment: Question 2: Is there a way to sort the `items` list itself so that I don't have to use the `sortedArr` as the index? And instead just use `items[currentIndex]` to get the next element (according to `translate3d` position)?